# How to determine Blazor webassembly internal server error

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm just getting started learning Blazor.  I set up a new Blazor webassembly project.  I'm basically just trying to figure out how to set up a login page that swaps the layout after a successful login.  But, when I try to use the HttpClient to post the login model to the server I get an unhandled exception occurred, reload message.  I can't find anything in the event viewer and my breakpoint on the controller method it's calling never gets hit.  How can I figure out what the problem is?  Here's some of the code.

No matter what kind of error handling I try, all I get is the same error message below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorAppTest</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link href="BlazorAppTest.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Login component

```
@using BlazorAppTest.Shared.Domain.Login
@using System.Text
@inject HttpClient http

<div class="login-wrap">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Email address</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email address" class="form-control" @bind-value="emailaddress"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" @bind-value="password"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button id="btn-login" @onclick="login" class="btn btn-primary">Log In!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loggedErrorMessage))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            @loggedErrorMessage
        </div>   
    }
</div>

@code {
    private string? password;
    private string? emailaddress;
    private string? loggedErrorMessage;
    
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> LoginComplete { get; set; }

    public async Task login()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await http.GetAsync($"/Login/Validate?email={emailaddress}&password={password}");
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            var result = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<LoginResultViewModel>($"/Login/Validate?email={emailaddress}&password={password}");
            loggedErrorMessage = result?.LoginErrorMessage;
            await LoginComplete.InvokeAsync(result != null && result.LoggedIn);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using BlazorAppTest.Shared.Domain.Login;
using BlazorAppTest.Shared.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorAppTest.Server.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    private ILoginService _loginService;

    public LoginController(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Validate(string email, string password)
    {
        return Ok(_loginService.Login(email, password));
    }
}
```

Client Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using BlazorAppTest.Client;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Server Program.cs

```
using BlazorAppTest.Shared.Data;
using BlazorAppTest.Shared.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoginService, LoginService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoginRepository, LoginRepository>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "Open",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("Open");
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

LoginResultViewModel

```
namespace BlazorAppTest.Shared.Domain.Login;

public class LoginResultViewModel
{
    public bool LoggedIn { get; set; }
    public string? LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Error handling 101, add a `try catch` and handle the error that comes from the `Fetch/XHR`. Have you checked your browser's dev tools for the request and responses from your API?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  When I write out the exception, it's just showing that it couldn't parse the json from the result, which is the html of the error page being returned.

Comment: I personally don't use `GetFromJsonAsync`. Do a Get, read the status code, if success code parse. If not, handle error. The status code should say what the issue is. If it is 200, it means your path is clashing with another, or it's not found and blazor is returning HTML to say this. Dev tools should give you all the info you need.

Comment: Doing that just gives me a 500 error, which doesn't give me any information on what's happening in the server app.

Comment: Yes, these are the first steps to following good standards. Always manage errors. Did you read the response message that returned with the 500 status code? Very likely it either contains a stack trace, or an indication of what went wrong.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you injected `ILoginService`.

Comment: I'll check later when I can run the code again to see if the 500 error gives me any more information, but if I recall, I don't think that it did.  Where are you seeing the need for the ILoginService injection?  The razor page?  I didn't think it would need injected there since it was only being used on the server.

Comment: Check your server's `Program.cs`. There should be a dependency injection for `ILoginService`. It is missing from the code you posted in the question.

Comment: Ah yes, great catch.  Thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't gotten me any further.  No matter what I try, I always get back the same message from the server that an unhandled error has occurred.  Again, it never hits my controller method.  I've checked log files and can't find anything.  I've updated my post with a few code updates.

Comment: Decorate your endpoint with  `[HttpGet("validate")]` then it should work. I think you are not calling the Controller the way you are doing it now.

Comment: Ah geeze, yes... thank you, thank you, thank you!  That did it!